# FullSimplify missing trivial rewrite

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation

I'm trying to understand why *Mathematica* fails to find the Stirling numbers in the second sum below:

```
Sum[Binomial[n, m] * (-1)^(m) * (n - m)^t, {m, 0, n}] // FullSimplify
(* 
  n! StirlingS2[t, n]
*)

Sum[Binomial[n, n - m] * (-1)^(n - m) * m^t, {m, 0, n}] // FullSimplify
(* 
  Sum[(-1)^(-m + n) m^t Binomial[n, -m + n], {m, 0, n}]
*)
```

Clearly I've just substituted $n-m$ for $m$, but suddenly *Mathematica* fails to find anything. Did I miss something?

Comment: It is easy to find expressions that `FullSimplify` cannot handle, even though a person can.  `FullSimplify` tries numerous rules from a library of rules to obtain simplifications as defined by a `ComplexityFunction`.  To get from your second expression back to the first one, it would need to be able to transform the summation limits, for which it probably has no rules.

Comment: Ah, I was hoping I just needed to add some assumptions about the variables being integers or so. It seems strange if `Sum` doesn't try changing the summand, that seems like a very basic technique...

Comment: @Wizard I don't understand why they shouldn't be the same function?

Comment: @ThomasAhle: Sorry for that, I took a second look and you are right, it's the same function. I just got confused with m running from 0 to n the second time. My apologies.